How do i inject a global database connection?
I would like to make my Drupal readonly. And therefore replace the database connection via dependency injection with a custom connection... I've been trying around with the service for a long time but I'm not getting anywhere, so my question is:
Can I replace the connection directly via my_module.service.yml and if so, how or what am I doing wrong?
CustomConnection:
<?php

namespace Drupal\db_read_only\Database;

use Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseException;

/**
 * Read-only Connection class.
 */
class ReadOnlyConnection extends Connection {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct($connection, array $connection_options = []) {
    //throw new DatabaseException('This is a Test');
    parent::__construct($connection, $connection_options);
  }
  ....

db_read_only.services.yml:
services:
  database.default:
    class: 'Drupal\db_read_only\Database\ReadOnlyConnection'
    arguments: ['@database']
    

settings.php:
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'dbName',
    'username' => 'dbUser',
    'password' => 'dbPassword',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => 'dbHost',
    'port' => '3306',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    );

I am using Drupal 10.3.5.
Added:
class DbReadOnlyServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    if ($container->hasDefinition('database')) {
        
      $definition = $container->getDefinition('database');
      $definition->setClass('Drupal\db_read_only\Database\ReadOnlyConnection');
    }
  }
}


Have you read https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services?
You have invalid syntax there also. You are trying to pass a string, 'default' to a constructor parameter that requires an array.

Thanks for the link. I adopted my implementation a bit but couldn't get it running, not even the constructor is called (which would throw the commented exception). So believe my class is never correctly instantiated...

Either the class name is Drupal\my_module\Database\ReadOnlyConnection, or Drupal\db_read_only\Database\ReadOnlyConnection. The code is using both those class names, but only one is correct.

Yes, that where only for demo purposes, changed it for clarification

The services file should be named foo.services.yml, plural

Thank you, but i still dont get any sign that this class is used (instead of the original Connection class)...

An alternative could be to create a separate Mysql user account and only give that account select privileges, hence making it readonly. Then connect to that db user account when running your test..
CREATE USER 'readonly_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT ON database_name.* TO 'readonly_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
